# JQuery append to variable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building my own JS library backed by jquery. The constructor starts building on top of an existing div to flesh it out. In the library I am making an ajax call, so to this initial div I know how to append like (where this is the initial div passed in):

```
var t = this;
var sdiv = t.append("<ul class='foo'></ul>");
```

So now I need to loop through and append elements to the variable "sdiv". For some reason

```
$(sdiv).append("<li class='bar'>" + element[i] + "</li>");
```

isn't working/rendering. How do you append elements to other elements created as variables?

Thanks

Comment: What does the this in `var t = this` refer to? Could it be pointing to window? If not have you considered that it should be `var t = $(this)`?

Comment: sorry that was a mistype on my part

Comment: Correcting that should fix everything, right? Or is there an issue still outstanding?

Comment: @user3558931 there are other issues. See my answer for how to fix them.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, great! I see what you mean.

Comment: it was a mistype in the question, not the code. and the reference to `this` is for the object itself in the constructor class. However, the appendTo method seems to be working.

Comment: I am curious why this question was downvoted twice?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because `sdiv` will be the same as the `t` variable, as `append` returns the originally selected element.

Instead, create the `ul` in it's own variable, then use that reference when appending. Try this:

```
var $t = $(this);
var $sdiv = $('<ul />', { class: 'foo' }).appendTo($t);

// in your loop...
$('<li />', { class: 'bar', text: element[i] }).appendTo($sdiv);
```

Note that I also wrapped `this` in a jQuery object. Assuming this code is being executed in an event handler, you would need to do that.

Comment: the code is being executed in a constructor. however, you are correct the appendTo() now points to the right object! Thanks!

Comment: When using class as in `{ class: 'foo' }` we always have to write `"class"`.

Comment: @user3558931 class is not a reserved word in JS, there's no need to quote it: http://jsfiddle.net/Lk8m3/. Nothing wrong with it though if you prefer that though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is it just better practice to isolate the elements like class and text outside the object itself? (as i noticed you did that). Just for my own curiosity.

Comment: @user3581725 It's personal preference. I believe the method I use of passing properties in a separate object when creating an element is slightly quicker due to not having to split the string apart with Regex. Any gains are minimal.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, then I guess I miss-read the second to last paragraph on this page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: @user3558931 I think that's a hang over from an old version of jQuery which has not yet been updated. It may be the case that you need to quote class in older versions of IE - I've not tested those lately.

Answer (score 1):

@RoryMcCrossan has provided a great answer. Another approach could be as follows:

```
var $t = $(this)
var $sdiv = $('<ul class="foo"/>');
```

Then in your loop do the following:

```
 $sdiv.append( $('<ul class="bar"/>').text( element[i] ) );
```

Then finally append `$sdiv` to `$t`:

```
 $t.append( $sdiv );
```